# Determine IP to which HTTP request was addressed in http.Handler

Tags: http, go

I have the following setup:

The request is made to the server using one of its IP addresses - let's say either `192.168.0.1`(on eth0) or `192.168.0.2`(on eth1). The server is listening on all addresses on the local machine (e.g. `http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)`).

How can I determine in the server code from the request which network interface (or IP address) it was sent to?

`req.Host` contains the host name for the server. Moreover, I can't see anything in the request headers.

Comment: I would edit the question as the fact your Go code is a proxy is irrelevant to the question. The question is basically "how do I know the local address of a TCP connection which is carrying out an HTTP request being processed?"

Comment: thanks @kostix, I rephrased the question better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, I figured out this for http library source code - incoming address is stored in request context under http.LocalAddrContextKey key. So to extract incomming IP address you need to do

```
r.Context().Value(http.LocalAddrContextKey)
```

Comment: I'd look at the `ConnContext` callback of the `http.Server`: its second argument is a `net.Conn` of the client's connection, so one could probably call `LocalAddr()` on it and actually populate the context.

Comment: @Flimzy, no it works as expected: <https://play.golang.org/p/zTBqVQuZtFL> (I did a series of `curl -s http://address_or_hostname:8080/` calls; this is a Debian box with two known IPv4 localhost addresses, one IPv6 localhost address and a C-class address on a private LAN).

Comment: (Verified that the OP's method works identically). So I'd mark the answer as accepted (this is OK on StackOverflow).